# Two "From" clauses in a delete statement when using join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm new to SQL, just a question on delete statement, let's say we have below DML query:

```
DELETE FROM O
FROM dbo.Orders AS O
JOIN dbo.Customers AS C ON O.custid = C.custid
WHERE country = N'Brazil';
```

I don't understand why it has be a `FROM` keyword in the first place, can't it be like:

```
DELETE O
FROM dbo.Orders AS O
JOIN dbo.Customers AS C ON O.custid = C.custid
WHERE country = N'Brazil';
```

because for some other DML statement like 'Update', the syntax is :

```
UPDATE OD   // no 'from'
SET discount += 0.05
FROM dbo.OrderDetails AS OD
JOIN dbo.Orders AS O ON OD.orderid = O.orderid
WHERE O.custid = 1;
```

there is no something like :

```
UPDATE FROM OD ...
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `FROM` is optional in the `delete`.  I would write it as:

```
DELETE O
FROM dbo.Orders O JOIN
     dbo.Customers C
     ON O.custid = C.custid
WHERE country = N'Brazil';
```

That is, the `O` in `DELETE O` is the alias defined in the `FROM`.

The same is true for the `UPDATE`.

It so happens that SQL Server supports:

```
DELETE dbo.Orders
FROM dbo.Orders O JOIN
     dbo.Customers C
     ON O.custid = C.custid
WHERE country = N'Brazil';
```

In this case, the `dbo.Orders` refers to the "same" table reference as `O`.  I consider this to be very bad form, because it is inconsistent with the definition of aliases in all other SQL statements.